# Why does this code loops 16 times instead of 8?

Tags: javascript

```
var tops = 5;

while (tops > 0) {
    for (var spins = 0; spins < 3; spins++) {
        alert("Top is spinning!");
    }
    tops = tops - 1;
}
```

Doesn't the var = spins loops 2 times each time the var = tops decreases by one until it gets to the value of 1? Wouldn't that code alert 8 times? I don't know why I get the alert 16 times.

Comment: That inner loop should run three times (0, 1, 2)

Comment: Replace `alert()` with `console.log(tops, spins)` - you'll see that you're actually getting 15 alerts (3 spins for each top), not 16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get the alert 15 times, not 8 or 16.

The values of `tops` are 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. For each of these values, `spins` will be set to 0, 1 and 2.

5 (values for tops) X 3 (values for spins) = 15

Comment: wow I really can't believe I was being this blind. That was really easy and obvious. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @RufioLJ sometimes it just needs a fresh pair of eyes ;) you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can just print to the screen the values of your variables(tops, spins).
Then you'll see that it loops 15 times and you'll see why.

Here is the jsFiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/66UuT/

Answer (score 0):

you `spins` loops for 3 times not 2 times as you are starting it from `0`